# Importing Granim into Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Following https://www.npmjs.com/package/granim will not be enough to use Granim with Vue-CLI.

Possible errors:

1. `ReferenceError: Granim is not defined`
2. `Module not found: Error: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] '\node_modules\Granim\index.js' does not match the corresponding path on disk granim`

Have answered below

Answer (score 1):

Usually, as in the case with particles.js you would need to `import 'particles.js'`.

However in this case you need to `import granim from 'granim'` and use `var granimInstance = new granim` instead of `var granimInstance = new Granim` as per npm snippet.